# ScanditSDKBarcodePicker alloc-init crash

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I have strange problem with my application which uses scandit SDK for barcode scanning.

The next line

```
ScanditSDKBarcodePicker *scanditSDKBarcodePicker = [[ScanditSDKBarcodePicker alloc] initWithAppKey:kAppKey];
```

crashes application with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code. Also I got next code as cause of app crash:

```
0xf0a9c:  push   {r7, lr}
0xf0a9e:  add    r7, sp, #0
0xf0aa0:  movs   r0, #1
0xf0aa2:  movw   r1, #65535
0xf0aa6:  bl     #-114                    ; 0x000f0a38 __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
0xf0aaa:  pop    {r7, pc}
0xf0aac:  lsls   r0, r6
```

Note: This problem does not happen every time the code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is Christian from Scandit.

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS could be caused by a problem with the app key/license integration. Can you double-check that the license key and app key are properly integrated?

You might also want to double-check whether the problem also occurs with the demo app that comes with the free development kit of our ios barcode scanner - after you integrated the license there.

Comment: If you want to be known as "Christian from Scandit" I suggest you modify your name and profile information accordingly.

Comment: Hi Christian, as you mentioned i just checked with the demo app and it works fine. I integrated scandit sdk to my app and there too it works fine for first launch. Issue here is with the second launch of the application as indicated by mperovic.